# Countdown Timer Not Working on iOS 6

Tags: ios, uilabel, nsdate, nstimer, countdown

I have a countdown timer in my app.  It counts down the days, hours, minutes, and seconds until a certain day arrives.  I accomplish this with the code listed below.  There are a total of 9 labels in the view.  4 that display the hours that are left, and 4 immediately below each of those that simply label each of the above labels as days, hours, minutes, and seconds.  The 9th label is one that covers all the rest of those up, and is supposed to stay hidden until the day arrives, and it says It's Time To Begin.  Here is my code.

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
  [self performSelector:@selector(updateCountdown) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];

}
- (void)updateCounter:(NSTimer *)theTimer {
    if(secondsLeft > 0 ){
        secondsLeft -- ;
        days = secondsLeft / 86400;
        NSLog(@"Notgreaterthan0%d", days);
        hours = secondsLeft / 3600;
        minutes = (secondsLeft % 3600) / 60;
        seconds = (secondsLeft %3600) % 60;
        dayslabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d", days];
        hourslabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d", hours];
        minuteslabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d", minutes];
        secondslabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d", seconds];
        beginLabel.hidden = YES;
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"BEGIN");
        //myCounterLabel.text = @"It's Time To Begin";
        beginLabel.hidden = NO;
        beginLabel.text = @"It's Time To Begin!";
    }
}

- (void)updateCountdown {
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd"];
    NSLog(@"updateCountdownmethod");
    NSDate *endingDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2013-12-27"];
    NSDate *startingDate = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSUInteger unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit|NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit|NSSecondCalendarUnit;
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:startingDate toDate:endingDate options:0];

    NSInteger days     = [dateComponents day];
    NSInteger hours    = [dateComponents hour];
    NSInteger minutes  = [dateComponents minute];
    NSInteger seconds  = [dateComponents second];
    NSLog(@"TESTTESTTEST%ld%ld%ld%ld",(long)days, (long)minutes, (long)seconds, (long)hours);
    if (days > 0 | hours > 0 | minutes > 0 | seconds > 0 ) {
        dayslabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d", days];
        hourslabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d", hours];
        minuteslabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d", minutes];
        secondslabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d", seconds];
        itsaysdays.hidden = NO;
        itsayshours.hidden = NO;
        itsaysminutes.hidden = NO;
        itsaysseconds.hidden = NO;

        beginLabel.hidden = YES;
        [self performSelector:@selector(updateCountdown) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
    }
    else {
        dayslabel.hidden = YES;
        hourslabel.hidden = YES;
        minuteslabel.hidden = YES;
        secondslabel.hidden = YES;
        beginLabel.hidden = NO;
        itsaysdays.hidden = YES;
        itsayshours.hidden = YES;
        itsaysminutes.hidden = YES;
        itsaysseconds.hidden = YES;
        beginLabel.text = @"It's time to begin!";

    }

}
```

This all works fine on iOS 7, but on anything lower, it instantly displays the It's Time To Begin label, covering up the rest.  My log for TESTESTEST(wanted it to be noticeable) came back with

```
22-28-3-8
```

So I know that it is getting the time correctly, but for some reason ignoring the if statement that is supposed to keep everything hidden correctly.

UPDATE:  I have tried switching dates on fromDate toDate section of code, and it still messes up.  For some reason it is just coming back with completely wrong NSDateComponents on iOS 6

Comment: Your `if` statement is using the wrong "or" operator. It's using arithmetic or instead of logical or. You should be using `||`. Not sure if that's the issue, but thought you should know.

Comment: Thanks.  Looks like the issue right now is that on iOS 6, the NSInteger for each of the components comes back negative.  On iOS 7 they come back as expected and positive. @user1118321